# How can I get 5 most viewed products per customer?

Tags: sql, hiveql, hue

I need help with a query to extract the top 5 most viewed products per customer in the last week. I know basic SQL so any help would be appreciated.

My tables look like this

db1.views

```
cust_id    hit    date_hit      prod_id
111        abc    [timestamp]   12345  
222        bcs    [timestamp]   87653       
333        pdr    [timestamp]   36702
444        lao    [timestamp]   90165
444        afe    [timestamp]   89104
333        wgt    [timestamp]   46177
111        gfr    [timestamp]   46468
```

db2.item

```
prod_id     color
 12345      red   
 87653      green   
 36702      blue   
 90165      red      
 89104      green     
 46177      yellow   
 46468      pink
```

db3.price

```
 prod_id     price
     12345      500
     87653      450
     36702      600
     90165      570
     89104      650
     46177      430
     46468      900
```

This was my original query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(v.hit) AS hit, i.prod_id, v.cust_id
FROM db1.views v
JOIN db2.item i
    ON v.prod_id = i.prod_id
JOIN db3.price p
    ON i.prod_id = p.prod_id
WHERE  i.color = "red" OR p.price > 500)
GROUP BY i.prod_id, v.cust_id
) AS A
JOIN db1.views B
    ON A.prod_id = B.prod_id
WHERE A.hit>1 AND B.date_hit BETWEEN date_sub(current_timestamp(), 7) AND current_timestamp()
```

Unfortunately with this one I could not find a way to limit my results to the 5 prod_id with the most views.

I then read around and found the rank() and row_number() functions, and started trying something like this:

```
SELECT rank() over(PARTITION BY A.prod_id ORDER BY A.hits DESC) AS row_num
FROM (
    SELECT i.prod_id, COUNT(v.hit) AS hits
FROM db1.views v 
JOIN db2.item i
    ON v.prod_id = i.prod_id
JOIN db3.price p
    ON i.prod_id = p.prod_id
WHERE i.color = "red" OR p.price > 500
GROUP BY i.prod_id
SORT BY hits DESC) AS A
GROUP BY A.prod_id, A.hits;
```

My issue with this one is that it always, always times out! I'm not sure if I have a syntax error or if I'm doing something that SQL is unable to resolve but I haven't been able to have this one work. I tried the same with `row_number()` and didn't work either. I feel like I might be close with this one but I'm not sure why it keeps timing out. Also, I know this second one does not have the cust_id, it's only because I can't even make it work at the moment.

What I'd like to have is something like this:

```
   cust_id    hit   prod_id
    111       50     84304
    111       45     12345  
    111       42     16730
    111       11     17592
    111       4      43024
    222       93     87653       
    222       91     23489
    222       34     83920
    222       22     57482
    222       20     38402
    333       43     36702
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to count the views and then window functions to determine the top 5:

```
select vc.*
from (select v.cust_id, v.prod_id, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by v.cust_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from views v
      where v.timestamp > date_sub(current_timestamp(), 7)
      group by v.cust_id, v.prod_id
     ) vc
where seqnum <= 5;
```